# Associate comments with an already authorized user?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-comments, django-1.10

My task is to create **comment system** in django project. I am tring to use [django-comments-xtd](https://github.com/danirus/django-comments-xtd) app.

I successfully added this app to my project and use `{% render_comment_form for object %}` in template. Is shows me fields like `"Name"`, `"Email"`, `"Url"` and `"Comment"`.

Maybe someone who worked with this app could answer me. Is it possible to show only "Сomment" field and associate comments with an already authorized user. Right now all unregistered users can comment. What I need to customize? I am little bit comfused with this app.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to only show the comments and the comment form to authorized user. In that case, you could wrap it with an `if` statement like this:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  {% render_comment_form for object %}
{% endif %}
```